# What part of speech is the word "outside" in "I'm outside your house"?

Tags: parts-of-speech

I'm wondering what part of speech is the word "outside" in the sentence "I'm outside your house". I checked the dictionary and it can be noun/adjective/adverb/preposition. When it comes to pronunciation, all of them seem to have different stress patterns, so it would be helpful for me to know what part of speech is the word "outside" in the sentence "I'm outside your house." I would be grateful for any suggestion. Thank you!

Comment: It's a preposition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would take it as a preposition.  It is exactly parallel to

> I'm in your house.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with @Colin Fine that it's a preposition. But I wanted to add a few words about prepositions in general.

A preposition links a noun phrase with another part of the sentence. In your example, "outside" links the noun "house" with the rest of the sentence.

Prepositions are important. Here are some other examples.

1. I am sitting on the roof. (The preposition "on" links "roof" with the rest of the sentence.)
2. The bird flew over the roof. (Preposition: "over")
3. Father jumped down from the roof. (Preposition: "from")